# Why is it not showing the user? discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is my code

```
 const reaction = m.reactions.cache.find(r => r.emoji.name == ''); 
   const userss = reaction.users.cache.random(1);
message.channel.send(`${userss} has won the giveaway!`);
```

The problem is that it won't show the user who won the giveaway, it just shows this:
[image]

Any Idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I need to know the context, apparently you did not assign a `try/catch` to know why you are not displaying the user. Try writing a `console.log()` in the **userss** variable to see what is returning!

Comment: Okay, I did that and in the console log it says []

Comment: Try to debug exactly on the line: `reaction.users.cache.random (1);` without assigning it to the variable, as the code is incomplete in your question, it is difficult to identify the real problem, if possible, publish the code, editing your publication and clicking on javascript code tool!